# How to make a link in html to start the timer in java?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I added the code bellow...
So, basically, its a timer, that starts every 7 seconds to write something in the console...

now i have a html page...from witch i want to make a link...
and that link should start the timer...

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    timerService.createTimer(1000, 7000, "1");
}
```

the code above set the timer to 7 sec, and i pass the arg 1 to it...i need it later on...

```
// public Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(1000, 10000, "1");



@Timeout
@GET
@Path("/timerStart")
public void TimeOut(Timer timer) {

    /*
     * String ss = timer.getInfo().toString(); String brojS =
     * ss.substring(0, 1); ss.substring(1);
     */
    Long brojI = Long.parseLong(timer.getInfo().toString(), 10);
    // HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) timer.getInfo().
    // //@Context HttpServletRequest req
    // execute(,brojI);

    System.out.println("Timer Service : " + timer.getInfo());
    System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
    System.out.println("Next Timeout : " + timer.getNextTimeout());
    System.out.println("Time Remaining : " + timer.getTimeRemaining());
    System.out.println("____________________________________________");

}
```

the problem is, that once i run the server...the timer starts also...and thats a problem...i need him to start once i press the link on the html page...

any suggestions?

Comment: You need to understand that the HTML is not capable of running the timer on its own since HTML runs on your browser, and Java code runs on a server (maybe a different machine). You need to instruct the server to start the timer. AJAX does that. Read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag and use `onclick` event to trigger an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

**HTML**

```
<a href="" onclick="someFunction()"> Start Timer</a>
```

**JS**

```
somefunction(){
  // ajax request
}
```

Comment: how should i do that? i only have a simple html page with the following line <a href="rest/dss/timerStart">Start Timer</a>

Comment: Click on the link(highlighted in blue) to know more about each functionality. Not sure if you are using any java framework like spring

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

This goes into the html page:

```
<a href="rest/dss/startTimers">Start Timer</a>
```

and this goes into the code:

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

@GET
@Path("/startTimers")
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Started the timer!");
    timerService.createTimer(1000, 1000, "1");
}

@Timeout
public void execute(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("Timer Service : " + scriptId);
    System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
    System.out.println("Next Timeout : " + timer.getNextTimeout());
    System.out.println("Time Remaining : " + timer.getTimeRemaining());
    System.out.println("____________________________________________");

}
```

and btw, here is a code to stop the timer:

```
@GET
@Path("/stopAllTimers")
public void StopTimer() {

    for (Timer timer : timerService.getAllTimers()) {
        System.out.println("All Timers Stopped");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

and the link in the html page:

```
<a href="rest/dss/stopAllTimers">Stop All Timers</a>
```